# Is it good practice to wrap StatefulWidgets inside StatelessWidgets?

Tags: performance, flutter

I know that `StatelessWidgets` have no state that will change on a later stage on the other hand `StateFulWidgets` do. So is it a good idea to keep only the changeable part inside a stateful widget and then use it along with the rest of the UI inside a stateless widget?

For example, if I have a page which has a date picker, then I need to have a stateful widget to hold that date control but the rest of the UI which will actually use the picked date doesn't change. So will it give more performance especially w.r.t. the widget rebuilding perspective if I make the date control a stateful widget and hold it inside a stateless widget? I mean in that case will the parent widget get rebuilt when the date is picked?

Comment: weird and premature optimisation

Comment: @GenchiGenbutsu Would you mind explaining a little why you think so

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is okay to put a stateful widget inside a stateless widget for optimization purposes. When the stateful widget redraws, the stateless widget will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your good question!

The answer is to use the [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package and wrap the widget that needs to be changed in a *Consumer* widget. It listens for changes and rebuilds just what you need, without rebuilding the entire widget tree.

This video explains it well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkFjtCov62g

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to do so.
In fact the Flutter default app code uses this.